# Is it possible to add a NULL row in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Is it possible to add a new column using Azure Synapse Data flow?
Normally you would not add a Null row, but in our case we need that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the above scenario in my environment and able to add a row with NULL values like below.

In dataflow, we cannot give `null()` expression to a column directly because **it requires data type for it**. So, in this scenario I am generating columns with null values of type **String**.

After Generating these columns, **I am getting a single unique row(nulls)** from it and **adding it to original data using union transformation**.

But for this, ***you should have same data types for union input columns***.

Thats why give the **`string` datatype** for all the columns at the beginning of source projection as we are generating the null values in string format only.

After adding null row, **you can convert all columns to their respective data types using cast transformation** and this is the limitation of this approach.

[image]

This is my sample data:

[image]

Then I have used derived column transformation with dynamic column pattern with `String(null())` as value which gave the following results.

[image]

To get a single record of null values, I have used aggregate transformation with **Group by** `Id` and in **Aggregates** I have given `first($$)` with dynamic column pattern. This is the result of it.

[image]

Now, use union transformation by name with `Source1` and the above `aggregate1` and you can see the null row was added.

[image]

But the above result includes of string type. So, convert these to their respective data types using cast trasformation like below.

[image]

**This is my Dataflow JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "aggregate1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DerivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "cast1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as string,",
                "          Name as string,",
                "          Age as string,",
                "          marks as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1, aggregate1 union(byName: true)~> union1",
                "DerivedColumn1 aggregate(groupBy(Id),",
                "     each(match(name!='Id'), $$ = first($$))) ~> aggregate1",
                "source1 derive(each(match(true()), $$ = toString(null()))) ~> DerivedColumn1",
                "union1 cast(output(",
                "          Id as integer,",
                "          Name as string,",
                "          Age as integer,",
                "          marks as integer",
                "     ),",
                "     errors: true) ~> cast1",
                "cast1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['target.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

[image]